# Js site does not return data on shaving

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using the script I always use to scrape data from the web but I'm not getting success.

I would like to get the data from the table on the website:

https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx

I'm using the following code for scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(bs)
```

currently I only receive js from the site and not the data from the table itself

Answer (score 0):

Do HTTP POST to https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/PopulaComboEmpresas

This will return you data of the table as JSON.

In the browser do F12 --> Network --> Fetch/XHR in order to see more details like HTTP header and POST Body.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using only requests as api calls json response and following the post method.

Here is the working code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

body = { 'tipoEmpresa': '0'}  

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
    'x-dtpc': '33$511511524_409h2vHHVRBIAIGILPJNCRGRCECUBIACWCBUEE-0e37',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }


url='https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmConsultaExternaCVM.aspx/PopulaComboEmpresas' 
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers =headers, verify = False)
res =  r.json()['d']
print(res)
```